# AJAX success response fires error callback

Tags: c#, json, ajax, razor

I spent yesterday wondering around in SO for something that would suit me i haven't found anything appropriate.
I'm having a quite common problem with the response of an ajax call from a razor view.
For test purpose i'm forcing a success response to be returned as a Json response:

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Save(int order){
      . . .
      var response = new {Order = order, ResultCode = 0, ResultMessage = "Positive!", Success = true };
      var json = Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      return json;
```

Ajax call as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#save_ahref").click(
            function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "/MyController/Save",
                    dataType: "application/json",
                    data: { order: $("#hid_order").val() },
                    success: onSuccess,
                    error: onError
                });
            }
        );
    });

    function onSuccess(response) {
        //never reached
    }

    function onError(response) {
        var res = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
       //do  other stuff
    }
```

My response from Chrome console looks correct:

```
    Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "{"Order":12345678,"Success":true,"ResultCode":0,"ResultMessage":"Positive!"}", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}
```

and the result of the JSON.parse(response.responseText) as well (jsonlint says so).

Although i followed the hints found here in SO and other forums (they all basically say to use application/json instead of json as dataType, and try to parse correctly the object) i still get the error event fired and i can't seem to get why.

I would be grateful for any idea!

Comment: my workoround was to simply intercept the result on complete, ignoring the fact that the response was a success or a fail.

Comment: The onComplete callback parses the json object in the result and does things accordingly to the value of response.Success.